# value of checked button is coming undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to work on one problem with ice-cream selection machine in which user can select the different options and get the according results.

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 1</h1>
        <div class="question">What color are you wearing?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="strawberryflavor" data-text-swap="Pink" data-text-original="Strawberry">Pink</button>
          <button name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="ooptions-button fruits" value="chocolateflavor" data-text-swap="Brown" data-text-original="Chocolate">Brown</button>
          <button  name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="vanillaflavor" data-text-swap="White" data-text-original="Vanilla">White</button>
          <button  name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="cookiencreamflavor" data-text-swap="BW" data-text-original="CookieNCream">BW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="raspberryflavor" data-text-swap="Red" data-text-original="Raspberry">Red</button>
          <button  name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() " class="options-button fruits" value="mintchipsflavor" data-text-swap="Green" data-text-original="Mint Chips">Green</button>
          <button name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="peanutbutterflavor" data-text-swap="Yellow" data-text-original="Peanut Butter">Yellow</button>
          <button name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor() "class="options-button fruits" value="coffeeflavor" data-text-swap="Black" data-text-original="Coffee">Black</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 2</h1>
        <div class="question">Whom do you want to have ice cream with right now?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce()" class="options-button sauce" value="marshmellowsauce" data-text-swap="Marshmellow Man" data-text-original="Marshmellow Sauce">Marshmellow Man</button>
          <button name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce()" class="options-button sauce" value="peanutbuttersauce" data-text-swap="Mr.Peanut Butter" data-text-original="Peanut Butter Sauce">MR. Peanut Butter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce()" class="options-button sauce" value="hotfudgesauce" data-text-swap="Willy Wonka" data-text-original="Hot Fudge Sauce">Willy Wonka</button>
          <button name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce()" class="options-button sauce" value="nosauce" data-text-swap="Alone" data-text-original="No Sauce">Alone</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 3</h1>
        <div class="question">What's the weather like right now?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles()"class="options-button sprinkles" value="yogurtchips" data-text-swap="Snow" data-text-original="Yogurt Chips">Snow</button>
          <button  name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles()"class="options-button sprinkles" value="chocolatechips" data-text-swap="Rainy" data-text-original="Chocolate Chips">Rainy</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles()"class="options-button sprinkles" value="mm" data-text-swap="Sunny" data-text-original="M&M">Sunny</button>
          <button  name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles()"class="options-button sprinkles" value="coconutchips" data-text-swap="Cloudy" data-text-original="Coconut Chips">Cloudy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 4</h1>
        <div class="question">How are you feeling right now?</div>
  
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="mango" data-text-swap="Angry" data-text-original="Mango">Angry</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="pineapple" data-text-swap="Jealous" data-text-original="Pineapple">Jealous</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="raspberry" data-text-swap="Upset" data-text-original="Raspberry">Upset</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="blueberry" data-text-swap="Sad" data-text-original="Blueberry">Sad</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="strawberry" data-text-swap="Fantastic" data-text-original="Strawberry">Fantastic</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="healthbar">Energetic</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="item map-text">Get your "ice-cream of the day" at the nearest J. P. Licks store!
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="icecream_image">
  
      <div id="order-summary"></div>
  
      
    </div>
<script>

var order = document.getElementById('order');

var orderSummary = document.getElementById('order-summary');

var flavorOptions = document.getElementsByName('flavor');
var flavorChosen;
function chooseFlavor() {
  console.log("flavor is running");
  
  if (flavorOptions[0].checked== true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[0].value;
    
  } else if (flavorOptions[1].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[1].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[2].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[2].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[3].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[3].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[4].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[4].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[5].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[5].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[6].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[6].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[7].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[7].value;
  } 
}

var sauceOptions = document.getElementsByName('sauce');
var sauceChosen;
function chooseSauce() {
  console.log("sauce is running");
  
  if (sauceOptions[0].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[0].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[1].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[1].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[2].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[2].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[3].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[3].value;
  }
}

var sprinklesOptions = document.getElementsByName('sprinkles');
var sprinklesChosen;
function chooseSprinkles() {
  console.log("sprinkles is running");
  
  if (sprinklesOptions[0].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[0].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[1].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[1].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[2].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[2].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[3].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[3].value;
  }
}

var fruitsOptions = document.getElementsByName('fruits');
var fruitsChosen;
function chooseFruits() {
  console.log("fruits is running");
 
  if (fruitsOptions[0].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[0].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[1].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[1].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[2].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[2].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[3].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[3].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[4].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[4].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[5].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[5].value;
  }
}


order.addEventListener('click', printOrder);

function printOrder() {
  console.log('order summary');
  var orderText = 'You got a ' + flavorChosen + 'icecream with' + sauceChosen + ' ' + sprinklesChosen + 'and ' + fruitsChosen + '.'
  var orderP = document.createElement('p');
  orderP.innerHTML = orderText;
  orderSummary.appendChild(orderP);
}
</script>
```

the result should be selections result at the last line according to the options you selected.I have worked with different ways to get the button click but none of them working properly.

i cannot click all the buttons except the first one and still i am getting undefined values on my all variables.please guide me for the event clicking and storing in variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any elements with `className` `flavor`

Instead, use:

```
var flavorOptions = document.getElementsByName('flavor');
```

The same applies for all the others too

```
var sauceOptions = document.getElementsByName('sauce');
var sprinklesOptions = document.getElementsByName('sprinkles');
var fruitsOptions = document.getElementsByName('fruits');
```

Comment: thanks , i changed the ByName still the values are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to assign the `class` on all your controls and then access them in your js code.You are accessing data based on index which is not a good practice.
Try to avoid that.

```
var flavorOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('fruits');
if (flavorOptions .checked)
{
    // ..
}
```

Comment: thanks , i have tried this way still the value is undefined